# android select data of database with order

Tags: android

in my android app i request data of my local database and give them out into a list view.

now i would like to sort my query, but this doesn't work :(
i try it with this code:

```
   String query = "SELECT * FROM "+DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+" " +
                "WHERE name= 'Max' " +
                "ORDER BY '"+DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SECONDNAME+"' DESC";    
Cursor c1 = dbHandler.selectQuery(query);

Cursor c1 = dbHandler.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DatabaseListItems databaseListItems = new DatabaseListItems();

                databaseListItems.setID(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("id")));

                databaseListItems.setFirstName(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Firstname")));

                databaseListItems.setSecondname(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Secondname")));

                databaseList.add(databaseListItems);

            } while (c1.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    c1.close();
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: try directly `"ORDER BY "+DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SECONDNAME+" DESC";   do not need single quote`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
"ORDER BY '"+DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SECONDNAME+"' DESC"
```

to

```
"ORDER BY "+DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SECONDNAME+" DESC"
```

You have to drop the single quotes, it's invalid **SQL** syntax.